# React Navigation Prevents text input from focusing at first try

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello Everyone i have the exact same problem with this one. but the question has no answer yet

im stuck with this all day there is no answer to found i am using the latest react native and latest react navigation package

[React navigation focus on input blurs immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056722/react-navigation-focus-on-input-blurs-immediately-when-going-back-to-previous-sc)

so this is my form page where at the first load blurs text input when  i click the text box

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Dimensions } from 'react-native'

 import { 
Container, 
Content, 
Button, 
Text,
Form,
Item,
Input,
Label,
Textarea
} from 'native-base';

import Ion from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

class Compose extends Component{
render(){
    return(
        <Container>
            <Content>
                <Form style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                    <Item inlineLabel style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                        <Ion name="ios-person" size={25} style={{ marginRight: 12 }}/>
                        <Label>Product Name*</Label>
                        <Input 

                        />
                    </Item>
                    <Item inlineLabel style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                        <Ion name="md-pricetags" size={25} style={{ marginRight: 12 }}/>
                        <Label>Price*</Label>
                        <Input 

                        />
                    </Item>
                    <Item inlineLabel style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                        <Ion name="md-arrow-down" size={25} style={{ marginRight: 12 }}/>
                        <Label>Drop rate*</Label>
                        <Input 

                        />
                    </Item>
                    <Item inlineLabel style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                        <Ion name="md-phone-portrait" size={25} style={{ marginRight: 12 }}/>
                        <Label>Contact number*</Label>
                        <Input 

                        />
                    </Item>
                    <Textarea 
                        rowSpan={5} bordered
                        placeholder="Description"
                        style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}
                    />
                    <Button block success style={{ height: 60, marginBottom: 14 }}>
                        <Ion name="md-images" size={25} style={{ color: 'white' }}/>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Upload Photos</Text>
                    </Button>
                    <Button block danger>
                        <Ion name="ios-cellular" size={25} style={{ color: 'white' }}/>
                        <Text>Broadcast</Text>
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </Content>
        </Container>
    )
}
}

export default Compose
```

and here is my navigation component

```
            import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import { Text } from 'react-native'

        //Navigation
        import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
        import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
        import { createStackNavigator, TransitionPresets } from '@react-navigation/stack';

        //Screens
        import { Welcome, Compose } from './src/index'

        import { 
            Header, 
            Left, 
            Button, 
            Icon, 
            Body, 
            Title, 
            Right
        } 
        from 'native-base'

        const Stack = createStackNavigator();

        const AppbarList = {
            welcome: function(navigation){
                return null
            },
            compose: function(navigation){
                return (
                    <Header>
                        <Left>
                            <Button transparent rounded>
                                <Icon name='arrow-back' onPress={()=>{ navigation.goBack() }}/>
                            </Button>
                        </Left>
                        <Body>
                            <Title></Title>
                        </Body>
                        <Right />
                    </Header>
                )
            }
        }

        const Appbar = ( scene, navigation )=> {
            const { options } = scene.descriptor;
            const title = scene.route.name;

            return AppbarList[title.toLowerCase()](navigation)
        }

        class App extends Component{
            render(){
                return(
                    <NavigationContainer>
                        <Stack.Navigator
                            headerMode="screen"
                            screenOptions={{
                                header: ({ navigation, scene, previous }) => Appbar( scene, navigation )
                            }}
                        >

                            <Stack.Screen
                                name="Welcome" component={Welcome} 
                                options={{
                                    ...TransitionPresets.FadeFromBottomAndroid,

                                }}
                            />
                            <Stack.Screen 
                                name="Compose" component={Compose}
                                options={{
                                    ...TransitionPresets.FadeFromBottomAndroid,

                                }}
                            />

                        </Stack.Navigator>
                    </NavigationContainer>
                )
            }
        }

        export default App;
```

Comment: Add code and show us what you did. don't rely on links to explain your question. What happens if that user deletes his/her question? Yours will have no context.

Comment: apart from that, creating a duplicate question on purpose might not be a good idea either.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Try to disable gestures for Android.

```
export default () => {
  const isAndroidPlatform = isAndroid();
  return {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      gestureEnabled: !isAndroidPlatform,
      cardOverlayEnabled: true,
      ...(
        isAndroidPlatform
          ? TransitionPresets.FadeFromBottomAndroid
          : TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS
      ),
    },
  };
};
```